Azure Open ID Connect You can not access this right now
I'm implementing Azure Open ID connect, and I get "You can not access this right now" initially when I enter my credentials.

But what's really interesting is that if I use the same URL, after the initial login, it works and I get the token back to the callback URL.
This is the URL I'm using.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=YYYYYYYYYYY&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7298%2Fapi%2FOIDCCallback&response_mode=form_post&scope=openid+profile+email&state=12345&nonce=678910
Does anyone know why it's not redirecting to the callback URL with the first login? and it works afterward?

Please share your Redirect URI in the registered app.

Does the call work after first login?

@Harshitha, it's https://localhost:7298/api/OIDCCallback.

@Rukmini, Yes, it works and I don't get that message after the first login. It only happens with the first login.

Did you try with any other user account?

I used the same endpoint and worked for the first login only:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7298/api/OIDCCallback
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid+profile+email
&state=12345



The issue you are facing might occurs due to several reasons.

Verify that the redirect URI (https://localhost:7298/api/OIDCCallback) is correctly registered in your Azure AD application settings and that it matches the one used in your authorization request.



The initial login state might not be properly established due to issues with cookies or sessions. Make sure your browser accepts cookies and check for any extensions that might interfere with the authentication process.
Check if there are any error messages or codes returned in the initial request’s response.
Ensure that the account being used is correctly configured in Azure AD and does not have any issues, such as being disabled or lacking the necessary permissions

